# cURL couldn't resolve host, but web browser can access it

Tags: c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm writing my server code in C on my Mac, and I need it to access Facebook's Graph API at the URL "https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=[insert access token here]". I'm getting a CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST error, maybe because I've never done this before and am probably doing something totally wrong. I'm setting up a CURL* and connecting like this:

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8");
char* httpURLFormat = "https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=%s";
char* httpURL = emalloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(httpURLFormat)+MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH)); //emalloc is just malloc that makes sure there is free memory
sprintf(httpURL, httpURLFormat, data->password); //data->password is the access token
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &httpURL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
struct url_data response; //this struct contains int size and char* data
response.size = 0;
response.data = emalloc(4096);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
CURLcode curlCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if (curlCode!=CURLE_OK){
    printf("curl failed!!!\n"); //this ends up printing
    free(response.data);
    free(httpURL);
    free(httpURLFormat);
    return false;
}
//Yes, I free everything left over afterwards...
```

I tested the URL it's connecting to in my web browser using the same user agent my code uses, and it connects without trouble. I tried adding a '\n' character to the end of the URL, and my code still won't work.

Comment: Can you try the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341644/curl-and-https-cannot-resolve-host? May be ssl, dns, or ipv6 issues. Also, can you try another API, e.g. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads?v=2&alt=json

Comment: Also, can you try simple request? e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/4

Comment: The simple request didn't work, but I realized why. Thanks for the link, but the DNS wasn't the problem. I realized that I have to specify the HTTPS port in the URL despite the https:// at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: The httpURLFormat should be "https://graph.facebook.com:443/app?access_token=%s". You need to specify the port in the URL. CURL apparently doesn't use the default 443 otherwise.