# Send sms using twilio and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, sms, twilio

I'm developing a web app using codeigniter,and i'm trying to send sms notifications using Twilio api,i tried using the twilio-ci library i found in github but it keep getting an error
**Curl failed with error Could not resolve host: api.twilio.com** 
anyone has an idea on how to send sms using codeigniter and twilio?

Comment: Have you searched any of [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341644/curl-and-https-cannot-resolve-host)s though?

Comment: Could you link the twilio-ci library that you found? I can't seem to find it. Also, have you tried the official Twilio PHP library? (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php)

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use the ci library when I was working on a Twilio project and it just never worked out.

While someone else pointed you to another answer, I do not believe it will work. Even when I was doing this last year the ci-library was badly out of date and I am not sure it has ever been updated

I would suggest using the standard Twilio Library. The only trick is you need to create a Helper file.

I will describe.

under the helper folder create a file my-twilio_helper.php

```
<?php
   if (!class_exists('Services_Twilio')) {
    include_once(APPPATH.'/libraries/Services/Twilio.php');
}

function get_twilio_service() {
    static $twilio_service;
    if (!($twilio_service instanceof Services_Twilio)) {

        $twilio_service = new Services_Twilio("sid", "auth");



    }
    return $twilio_service;
}
```

Then download the twilio Library into your libraries folder. You will just have a folder that says Services with all of the Twilio library inside.

After this I go into autoload.php and add it into my helper array like such

```
$autoload['helper'] = array("my-twilio", 'file');
```

Then in the controller files you call it

```
 //Calling the twilio help function to get the service
            $twilio = get_twilio_service();
            $sms = $twilio->account->messages->sendMessage(
                    'from', //from number 
                    $to, //To
                    'Message')

                    );
```

Comment: This is also not working for me. it showing "The configuration file twilio.php does not exist"