# php curl not working properly

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_errno($ch);
```

Always I am getting error **"curl error 6 couldn't resolve host"**
I have also checked phpinfo(). My curl functions are enabled there. Also allow_remote_url_open is also true at php.ini. and openssl is also enabled at phpinfo().

Is there any server specific settings, which is not helping curl to run ? Or do I need to check any other settings at php.ini ?

Comment: DNS issue? Can you ping it from the command line?

Comment: Seems to work fine... Check if you lost Internet connection at time of request

Comment: it's working at my end . check for this:-  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341688/4248328

Comment: It's working fine. Please check your end.

Comment: I didn't lost internet connection. It happens everytime when I make this request.

Comment: Try "file_get_contents( 'http://stackoverflow.com' )' instead of your whole script and post the result. This will allow you to know if the problem is curl-specific.