# PHP - Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException - Craft CMS

Tags: php, curl, eventbrite, craftcms

I'm running into an error with CURL on our staging server when trying to connect to the EventBrite API, despite local and production servers connecting just fine:

> [curl] 6: Could not resolve host: www.eventbriteapi.com; Name or service not known [url] https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?status=live%2Cstarted&order_by=start_asc&expand=category%2Cvenue%2Csubcategory%2Cformat%2Corganizer

We checked the curl command on the staging server which is also running normally. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a php-fpm issue - I found this article [CURL and HTTPS, "Cannot resolve host"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341644/curl-and-https-cannot-resolve-host)

Restarting php-fpm seems to be able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your curl url

```
[url] https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?status=live%2Cstarted&order_by=start_asc&expand=category%2Cvenue%2Csubcategory%2Cformat%2Corganizer
```

change this to

```
[url] https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events?status=live%2Cstarted&order_by=start_asc&expand=category%2Cvenue%2Csubcategory%2Cformat%2Corganizer
```

remove / after owned_events